# Scrapy:Using proxy middleware settings error

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm a scrapy newbie.I want to use proxy middleware.But my DEBUG messages show

```
2018-09-10 21:15:57 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2018-09-10 21:15:57 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2018-09-10 21:15:57 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2018-09-10 21:16:57 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2018-09-10 21:17:57 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2018-09-10 21:18:05 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry] DEBUG: Retrying <GET https://www.zhipin.com/robots.txt> (failed 1 times): TCP connection timed out: 110: Connection timed out.
2018-09-10 21:18:57 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
```

It will always crawl 0 pages and retry.My proxies are free and no authorization required.But I try to delete proxy middleware and use

`yield scrapy.Request(url='https://www.example.com/', callback=self.parse_first, meta=my_proxy)`

It's ok.It seems to be a problem with my settings.

Settings

```
DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware':135,
'ip_proxy.middlewares.CustomProxyMiddleware':125
}
```

CustomProxyMiddleware

```
class CustomProxyMiddleware(object):
def process_request(self, request, spider):
    request.meta['proxy'] = my_proxy
```

Spider

```
class ipSpider(scrapy.Spider):
  name = "test"

  def start_requests(self):
      yield scrapy.Request(url="https://www.example.com",callback=self.parse_first)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you haven't changed the default **ROBOTXT_OBEY** setting
Set **ROBOTXT_OBEY = False** and then try. I'll work.

Comment: Thanks!It works.But why does the robot.txt cause problems with my proxy ip?I think robot.txt just tells users which resources are not crawled.

Comment: robottxt is ment for robots (crawlers) servers specifies that these are the url which are allowed to crawl. If your scrapy crawler obeys that robots.txt then It'll first read that file and The url is disallowed by the server that you want to crawl then It'll skip crawling.